# First Scrapy crawler works, subsequent crawlers in sequence fail

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I have a script setup like below:

```
try:
    from Xinhua import Xinhua
except:
    error_message("Xinhua")

try:
    from China_Daily import China_Daily
except:
    error_message("China Daily")

try:
    from Global_Times import Global_Times
except:
    error_message("Global Times")

try:
    from Peoples_Daily import Peoples_Daily
except:
    error_message("People's Daily")
```

The purpose is to run a Scrapy crawler for each site, process the results, and upload those results to a database. When I run each script individually, each portion works fine. When I run from the block of code I've outlined, however, only the *first* Scrapy crawler actually works properly. All of the subsequent ones attempt to access the sites they are supposed to but don't return any results. I don't even get proper error messages back, just some "DEBUG... 200 None" and "[scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {}" lines. I also don't think the issue is my IP or anything being blocked; as soon as the crawlers fail I immediately launch them individually and they work great.

My guess is that the first crawler is leaving some settings behind that are interfering with the subsequent ones, but I haven't been able to find anything. I can rearrange the order of their execution and it is always the first in line that works while the others fail.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It is probably the twisted reactor. Your supsequent crawlers are likely trying to start a new one when the first one already exists.  It's hard to tell though with only this code.  How do you actually run the spiders after you import them?

Comment: They auto-run upon importation. It's also not just the spiders being imported, it is also several code blocks for processing and uploading the final processed results.

Comment: okay and how does each module start the spider?

Comment: Using process.crawl() and process.start()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue by combining each crawler into one script and running them with CrawlerProcess.

```
spider_settings = [
    {"FEEDS":{
        xh_crawl_results:{
            'format':'json',
            'overwrite':True
        }}},
    {"FEEDS":{
        cd_crawl_results:{
            'format':'json',
            'overwrite':True
        }}},
    {"FEEDS":{
        gt_crawl_results:{
            'format':'json',
            'overwrite':True
        }}},
    {"FEEDS":{
        pd_crawl_results:{
            'format':'json',
            'overwrite':True
        }}}
]
    
process_xh = CrawlerRunner(spider_settings[0])
process_cd = CrawlerRunner(spider_settings[1])
process_gt = CrawlerRunner(spider_settings[2])
process_pd = CrawlerRunner(spider_settings[3])

@defer.inlineCallbacks
def crawl():
    yield process_xh.crawl(XinhuaSpider)
    yield process_cd.crawl(ChinaDailySpider)
    yield process_gt.crawl(GlobalTimesSpider)
    yield process_pd.crawl(PeoplesDailySpider)
    reactor.stop()

print("Scraping started.")
crawl()
reactor.run()
print("Scraping completed.")
```

Comment: that will do.  I was going to recommend using a CrawlerRunner but i got busy yesterday sorry